# Nested ternary operator for react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I want to come up with a nested if ternary operator with react components but am being challenged , this is my logic :

```
if (value==='bank' && is_valid_iban && is_completed) {

return <Checked/>

}

else if (is_completed) {

return <Checked/>
}

else if (value==='businessplan' && is_required) {

return <NotChecked/>
}
```

This was my change :

```
{
(!value=== 'bank' || is_valid_iban) &&
                is_completed ? (<Checked/>) : (value ==='businessplan' && is_required && (<NotChecked/>))

}
```

What could be the best way of coming up with a ternary operator for the logic above.

Thanks

Comment: *want to come up with a nested if ternary operator* -- I strongly strongly advice against doing this. Nested ternaries are much more difficult to read and understand leading to a higher possibility of bugs. `if...else` is more verbose, but is the better way to go.

Comment: That said, you can simplify your `if...else`'s here. `((value==='bank' && is_valid_iban) || is_completed)` and then converting to a ternary is no longer nested.

Comment: Hi @BrianThompson and , just realised I missed another if statement kindly check my post of the edit

Answer (score 4):

This solution seeks to simplify the below given set of conditions:

```
if (value==='bank' && is_valid_iban && is_completed) {
  return <Checked/>
} else if (is_completed) {
  return <Checked/>
} else if (value==='businessplan' && is_required) {
  return <NotChecked/>
}
```

It is observed from the above that `is_completed` is part of the first & second conditions. Something like this: `((A && B && C) || C)` which can be represented as `(A && B) || C`.

Using a standard `if..else` structure:

```
if ((value === 'bank' && is_valid_iban) || is_completed) return <Checked />
else if (value === 'businessplan' && is_required) return <NotChecked />
else return null;
```

Using ternary `?:`

```
return (
  ((value === 'bank' && is_valid_iban) || is_completed)
  ? <Checked />
  : (value === 'businessplan' && is_required)
    ? <NotChecked />
    : null
);
```

When using `?:` please always indent the code so it is readable. Same applies for `if else` as well; however, the `if else` structure is a lot more readable than `?:`.

Answer (score 1):

Make it Simple:

```
  {(value === "bank" && is_valid_iban && is_completed) || is_completed ? (
    <Checked />
  ) : (value === "businessplan" && is_required) ? (
    <NotChecked />
  ) : (
    <NotChecked />
  )}
```

Comment: Hi Hridoy, thanks for the contribution, however please kindly read my question again, I forgot another IF statement, I editted it again.

Comment: Updated check it now.

Comment: Also return <NotChecked /> if there doesn't match any condition. That means the final else.

Comment: Welcome @Lutaaya Huzaifah Idris